# Buttons not working in Discord Py 2.0. When you click on the button, it displays the error below

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

Here is the code:

```
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Blurple Button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)  # or .primary
    async def blurple_button(self, button : discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print('1')
        button.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
```

Here is the error:

> Bot connection
> 1
> 2023-02-03 23:47:15 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view  for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Blurple Button' emoji=None row=None>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Andrej\3.Project\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
> > await item.callback(interaction)
> File "D:\Andrej\3.Project\Ecumonopolis 1.0\ecumenopolis ORM.py", line 506, in blurple_button
> > button.disabled = True
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'disabled'

Help me please. And help me figure out the buttons in Discord Py 2.0
Thank you in advance!

Help me please. And help me figure out the buttons in Discord Py 2.0
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```py
button.disabled = True
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'disabled'
```

As the error is telling you, your `button` argument is actually an `Interaction`, and vice-versa. You've got your arguments the wrong way around.

There are [official examples for views & buttons](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views) if you need them.

The tags in your post also suggest you're using a third-party package for buttons. There's no need for that, everything is built-in into `discord.py`.